# Organising postal address elements

Tags: c#

If I have the following postal address:

> Address1: NULL
>   Address2: 36
>   Address3: Moonrise Drive
>   Address4: NULL
>   Address5: London

I want to reformat the address so that I end up with:

> Address1: 36
>   Address2: Moonrise Drive
>   Address3: London
>   Address4: NULL
>   Address5: NULL

I started messing with SortedList but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

```
SortedList<int, string> AddressParts = new SortedList<int, string>();

 AddressParts.Add(1, IncomingAddress1);
 AddressParts.Add(2, IncomingAddress2);
 AddressParts.Add(3, IncomingAddress3);
 AddressParts.Add(4, IncomingAddress4);
 AddressParts.Add(5, IncomingAddress5);

SortedList<int, string> SortedAddressParts = new SortedList<int, string>();

 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in AddressParts)
 {
     if (pair.Key == 1 &&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.Value)) 
     { 
         SortedAddressParts.Add(1, pair.Value); 
     }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: write down the requirements for this first. Don't just start putting in sorted lists without first figuring out what/if you need to sort or not. For example: - needs to remove null values. - reorder entries by some criteria etc.

Comment: I presume the `Address1`...`Address5` elements are properties in a data object, not just indexed fields in a collection?

Comment: @slugster2, my address elements are just string variables.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming what you want is to put null lines at the end and keep the order of the text entries
consider doing like this:

```
public IList<string> FormatAddress(IList<string> addressParts)
{
    var result = addressParts.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)).ToList();
    result = result.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, addressParts.Count - result.Count)).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

It will work with any number of address lines and you just need to wrap those first in any kind of list.

Comment: Better is `AddressParts.Where(x => x != null).Concat(AddressParts.Where(x => x == null))`, more readable I guess..

Comment: Apologies I should have made it clearer in my original post! I'm a SQL Developer so I'm always thinking NULLs but this really could be NULL or empty string. I actually have my address elements as 5 string variables.

Comment: @nawal : if we go that route it would be better to just add the nulls in a for(int i = 0; i < addressParts.Count - result.Count; i++). That way you don't traverse the result twice and don't create intermediary lists. anyway i just wanted to point the OP to a solution not to give the best implementation possible :)

Comment: @nawal  good point then +1 to the comment. btw thanks for the formatting edit

Answer (score 1):

If you could represent your Address variables instead as an array then the following algorithm would achieve your desired result:

```
String[] address = {
    null,
    "36",
    "Moonrise Drive",
    null,
    "London"
};

List<String> address_new = new List<String>();

foreach (String s in address)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        address_new.Add(s);
}
for (int i = address_new.Count(); i < address.Length; i++)
{
    address_new.Add(String.Empty);
}
address = address_new.ToArray();
```

Comment: this solution reduces the count of the result lines. The OP seems to want the null values to appear at the end

Comment: Modified code to add null elements on the end up to the length of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to preserve the int `key` as well as change the order of `Values`. You can do something like:

```
var sorted = AddressParts.Where(x => x.Value != null) //or IsNullOrEmpty
                         .Concat(AddressParts.Where(x => x.Value == null))
                         .Select((x, i) => new { Key = i + 1, x.Value })
                         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

To get it in a `SortedList<,>`, just pass the dictionary to its constructor.

```
SortedAddressParts = new SortedList<int, string>(sorted);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want the addresses sorted too, you can use something like

```
int i = 1;
List<string> values = AddressParts.Values.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToList<string>();
SortedAddressParts = new SortedList<int, string>(values.ToDictionary(s => i++));
```

but this will sort the addresses too.